# Memorable Quotes

Tags: wordplay, music, quote

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

Based on the quotes, fill in the person who said them. The answer is a video game character.

____, in public place:

- "Seer prosecuted, ..."
- "...repair clothes with a needle? Not easy..."
- "...Ms Hathaway had received Chesterfield..."
- "...used Chesterfield, ultimately..."
- "...it does odd, grey, dark or laughing..."
- "...what Nancy Reagan might say about her children..."
- "...after summer, a city in the south of France..."
- "...King's book, *The Eye of Providence*, sees this..."
- "...interrupt what comes after the third act..."
- "...it remains unbalanced substance."

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first step is to realise that these lines:

> are **not actually quotes in themselves**. Instead, we first need to parse the wordplay to find synonyms of the words, and *then* we need to take 'soundalikes' - this is what the speech marks imply, *not* a direct quotation.

Doing so gives us the following:

*"Seer / prosecuted, ..."*

> EYE / TRIED = **I TRIED**

*"...repair clothes with a needle? / Not easy..."*

> SEW / HARD = **SO HARD**

*"...Ms Hathaway / had received / Chesterfield..."*

> [ANNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Hathaway) / GOT / [SOFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couch) = **AND GOT SO FAR**
>
>  (Music fans might spot at this point where this is going...!)

*"...used Chesterfield, / ultimately..."*

> [BUTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chesterfield_(cigarette)) / IN THE END = **BUT IN THE END**

*"...it does / odd, / grey, dark or laughing..."*

> IT DOES / NOT EVEN / MATTER = **IT DOESN'T EVEN MATTER**

*"...what Nancy Reagan might say about her children..."*

> "I HAD TWO" = **I HAD TO**

"...after summer, / a city in the south of France..."

> FALL / [TOULOUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toulouse) = **FALL TO LOSE**

*"...King's book, / The Eye of Providence, sees this..."*

> [IT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_(novel)) / [ALL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Providence) = **IT ALL**

*"...interrupt / what comes after the third act..."*

> BUTT IN / THE END = **BUT IN THE END**

*"...it remains unbalanced / substance."*

> IT DOESN'T EVEN / MATTER = **IT DOESN'T EVEN MATTER**

What have we produced here? These are:

> the lyrics to the chorus of [*In the End*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_End) (2000) by [Linkin Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkin_Park) (hence the [music](/questions/tagged/music) tag).

And this gives us our answer! These 'quotes' were said 'in public place' by:

> "[**Link**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(The_Legend_of_Zelda)), in park!"